# Tick data restructure using python

Tags: python, pandas

```
{origin:

2018-06-01T09:30:00.000+00:00   BID 30415.000       4   
2018-06-01T09:30:00.000+00:00   BID 30415.000       3   
2018-06-01T09:30:01.000+00:00   BID 30415.000       2   
2018-06-01T09:30:01.000+00:00   BID 30414.000       4   
2018-06-01T09:30:01.000+00:00   ASK 30416.000       1   
2018-06-01T09:30:01.000+00:00   ASK 30416.000       2   
2018-06-01T09:30:01.000+00:00   TRADE 30415.000     1
}
```

I would like to reformat the data to be like this:

> timestamp                      bid  bid_size  ask ask_size trade
>   trade_size

```
{2018-06-01T09:30:00.000+00:00  30415  4 nan nan nan nan

2018-06-01T09:30:00.000+00:00  30415  3 nan nan nan nan

2018-06-01T09:30:01.000+00:00  30415  2 30416 1 nan nan

2018-06-01T09:30:01.000+00:00  30415  4 30416 2 30415 1
}
```

Could you please help using Python? Also am encounter a problem that the duplicated timestamp issue I think it's because its tick data cause the same timestamp vs different bid size/ask size, and I also don't know how to correctly make them in sameline.

Comment: Why does the bid size rise to 4 on the 4th line?

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear from your example, but the first thing to do would be to load the data into a pandas DataFrame, called e.g. `df`, instead of a dictionary which it is right now. Make sure that this DataFrame has clear header names.

If you have the data in a panda DataFrame, you could use [`DataFrame.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot), see for more explanation [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html).

In your case you would end up with something like:

```
df.pivot(index=<Column1>, columns=<Column2>, values=<Column3>)
```

where you need to replace `<ColumnX>` with the appropriate headers that you provided.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Chan Kenneth: Can you please let us know if this helped or not?